# Utilize type hints over duck-typing for "@export var" for custom resource

Tags: gdscript, godot-4

I'm going through the ["Creating your own resources"](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/resources.html#creating-your-own-resources) steps. Here's an abbreviated version of the demo resource `bot_stats.tres` and the associated `bot_stats.gd` script:

```gdscript
extends Resource

@export var health: int

func _init(p_health = 0):
    health = p_health
```

And they suggest using it like this in another Node:

```gdscript
extends CharacterBody3D

@export var stats: Resource

func _ready():
    # Uses an implicit, duck-typed interface for any 'health'-compatible resources.
    if stats:
        stats.health = 10
        print(stats.health) # Prints "10"
```

Is it possibly to use a stronger type-hint? I'd love to have (and tried) something like:

```gdscript
@export var stats: BotStats
```

or

```gdscript
@export var stats: bot_stats
```

To get some intellisense rolling in the editor. But they give things like:

> Error at (3,18): Could not find type "BotStats" in the current scope.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give a class name to your custom `Resource` first. For example:

```
class_name BotStats
extends Resource

@export var health: int

func _init(p_health = 0):
    health = p_health
```

Then you should will be able to use that on the export variable:

```
@export var stats: BotStats
```

See [Static typing in GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html), [Registering named classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#registering-named-classes) and the [Resources section of GDScript exports](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#resources).

By the way, even though the term "type hint" stuck, these are actual type definitions, not just hints.

I also want to mention that this is not implemented properly in Godot 3.x at the time of writing (see [pull request 44879](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/44879)), there are workaround, but since you are for Godot 4, I'll not get into that. We can consider this a Godot 4 feature.